# Seeking for the suggestion for optimization in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, solver

I have a problem with optimization logic in python. I have create function for optimization. The logic is that I needed to change 2 parameters, which are `monthly_cci` and `rho`. The `monthly_cci` is random numpy array contained 40 values and the `rho` is a single value that must be positive (also randomly).

I needed these two parameters to fit with the formula to find the `fitted_upper`. I looped for 40 loops to get 40 `fitted_upper` as combined as single array called `monthly_fitted`. Then I transformed `monthly_fitted` with another formula to get `fitted_matrix`. I will the `fitted_matrix` to define error function, which is `error_matrix`.

I needed to minimized variance of the `error_matrix` as low as possible by changing the `monthly_cci` and `rho`. I have tried to code as below but it does not work. Any suggestion for this case?

Thank you!

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize   

def cci(monthly_cci, rho):
    monthly_cci = np.random.randn(40)
    rho = np.random.rand(1)

    monthly_fitted = []

    for i in range(0, len(monthly_cci)):
        fitted_upper = (upper_array - (np.sqrt(rho) * monthly_cci[i])) / np.sqrt(1 - rho)
        monthly_fitted.append(fitted_upper)

    monthly_fitted = np.vstack(monthly_fitted)

    #Fitted matrix

    m_0 = 1 - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 1])
    m_1 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 1]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 2])
    m_2 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 2]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 3])
    m_3 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 3]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 4])
    m_4 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 4])

    fitted_matrix = np.stack((m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4), axis = 1)
    fitted_matrix = fitted_matrix.reshape(cci['Monthkey'].max(), -1)

    error_matrix = n_array * ((monthly_array - fitted_matrix) ** 2) / (fitted_matrix * (1 - fitted_matrix))

    return np.var(error_matrix)

res = minimize(cci, x0 = [monthly_cci, rho], method='Nelder-Mead')
```

I got the error messages

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: @norok2 How do I suppose to do becasue each to array need another formual to transform

Comment: We may provide more help if you're able to provide MWE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems with the code which I can't solve because I don't have your setup, but I can help you with a few errors. Firstly in your minimisation function `cci` the input arguments are immediately overwritten, this won't work for minimisation so we remove them. Secondly, `minimize` will minimise scalar parameters. I'm assuming `monthly_cci` is some data you already have loaded, so we pass that to the `args` of `minimize`. I have edited your code to include these fixes:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize   
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

def cci(rho, monthly_cci):
    # we are minimising rho, so that is first argument
    # we pass through monthly_cci to args of minimise below
    
    # removed random variable creation
    upper_array = np.random.randn(40)

    monthly_fitted = []

    for i in range(0, len(monthly_cci)):
        fitted_upper = (upper_array - (np.sqrt(rho) * monthly_cci[i])) / np.sqrt(1 - rho)
        monthly_fitted.append(fitted_upper)

    monthly_fitted = np.vstack(monthly_fitted)

    #Fitted matrix

    m_0 = 1 - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 1])
    m_1 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 1]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 2])
    m_2 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 2]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 3])
    m_3 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 3]) - norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 4])
    m_4 = norm.cdf(monthly_fitted[0:, 4])

    fitted_matrix = np.stack((m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4), axis = 1)
    fitted_matrix = fitted_matrix.reshape(cci['Monthkey'].max(), -1)

    error_matrix = n_array * ((monthly_array - fitted_matrix) ** 2) / (fitted_matrix * (1 - fitted_matrix))

    return np.var(error_matrix)

# use test data
monhtly_cci = np.random.randn(40)
# x0 are the parameters to be minimises
# other arguments are passed as args
res = minimize(cci, x0=[rho], method='Nelder-Mead', args=(monthly_cci,))
```

Comment: I got the error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,5) (40,). Additionally, I don't want to minimize the rho but I needed to minimize variance of error_matrix by keep changing rho.

Comment: I don't have your data unfortunately so I cannot reproduce the whole example, and I can't say much to the error otherwise. Yes that's right, `minimize` will minimise the output to the objective function, in this case the variance of `error_matrix`, by optimising the value of `rho`.